# Can't bind NSArray with NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have an array (_websites) which returns 2 results (i can see the records using NSLog).

What I am trying to do is to display those 2 records in NSTableView that has 3 columns. I make numerous attempts to bind the content of my array with the NSArrayController, without any success.

Here is the .h file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface CombinedViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mObjContext;
@property AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *combinedRecordsArrayController;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray *websites;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

@end
```

the .m file code:

```
#import "CombinedViewController.h"
#import "Website.h"
#import "Customer.h"
#import "Hosting.h"

@interface CombinedViewController ()

@end

@implementation CombinedViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    _appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.mObjContext = _appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    [self getCombinedResutls];    

}

-(NSArray *)getCombinedResutls {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Website" inManagedObjectContext:self.mObjContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.mObjContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
    }
    _websites = [_mObjContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    for (Website *ws in _websites) {
        Customer *cust = ws.customerInfo;
        Hosting *host = ws.hostingInfo;

        NSLog(@"Website: %@, Customer: %@, Hosting Provider: %@",ws.websiteUrl, cust.customerName, host.hostingProvider);

    }

return fetchedObjects;
}


@end
```

I am trying to learn how to do it both ways, using cocoa binding and programmatically, so any kind solution will be appreciated. Links with some up to date tutorial will be also very welcomed.

I just forgot to mention...I bind the NSArrayController with ContentArray in Controller Content, and then I bind the NSTableView with the NSArrayController, as well as my Table Column,but I am getting empty NSTableView...no error is shown in console whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use direct iVar access-- `_websites`-- to write the `websites` property's iVar, the KVO notification that the binding depends upon never happens.

If you instead use `self.websites =`  or more explicitly `[self setWebsites: ...`, then you will trigger a KVO notification to the array controller that the value of the websites property has been updated.

Instead, the array controller in the Xib is unarchived and bound to `websites` before `viewDidLoad`, so at that point, `websites` is `nil`.  And subsequently, you never trigger any KVO notification about `websites` changing value because you explicitly avoid using the `websites` accessor `setWebsites` and instead use direct instance variable access.  So the AC never knows that `websites` changes and the table never reflects any value for `websites` except `nil`.

In general never use the instance variable to access a property's value unless you have a very good reason to do so and fully understand why you're doing so.

Comment: I have changed the _websites with self.websites in the 2 lines where I used it, and instead an empty nstableview, I now get error:the entity Website is not key value coding-compliant for the key "customerName" . What else I should change in my code?

Comment: You appear to use customerInfo in your code, not customerName

Comment: That is in the for loop, and if I use customerName there, displays error. I can't see any other place where I have customerInfo. CustomerInfo is the name of the relationship, (one to one)

Comment: Yeah, your implementation of website has customerInfo and not customerName.   The error message is pretty clear.  So you need to bind to some attribute on website that actually exists

Comment: How should I do that? I get kind of lost after so many hours trying to make this to work....

Comment: Verify what attributes your website entity has in the core data model, and ensure that the one you are binding to exists.   CustomerName doesn't.  Based on your code, customerInfo does.   Also, accept this answer and ask another question at this point... You're into basic core data questions and your first issue is resolved

Comment: Thanks. I think that I will resolve this soon with the help that you provide.

Comment: Thanks.  I should say that when you're down to "entity ___ not KVC compliant for key ___" you're pretty much down to a simple fix in the binding name in IB.